# "Not self-conscious at all.—No, that's a big part of it." What does it mean?

Tags: conversation

I am not a native English speaker and have been studying English. I was watching "Casual", and I didn't understand what they were talking about.

Alex asked Leon to have sex with two women. However, he kicked them out and he was in the living room. One girl came and talked to him, and they talked about Leon.

ALEX: Doing really well in there.

EMMY: He's doing very well.

ALEX: Not self-conscious at all.

EMMY: No, that's a big part of it.

I don't understand who is "Not self-conscious at all." and what the meaning is of "that's a big part of it" in this conversation. It might be a very strange question. However, please help me to improve my English skills and kindly inform me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Name the episode, provide a link to the TV series, we don't all watch the same programmes. Is it a comedy? Seems like it. Moreover, Alex can be the name of a woman or a man, it might be relevant then again it might not be. Lastly, did Leon kick out one or both women? It's unclear.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.  "Casual Season 1 #7". Alex is a men. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4657658/?ref_=tt_ep_nxponse.

Comment: It dose not mean anything. Don't worry about it.

Comment: There are a number of spelling and grammatical errors in your OP. For example it should be *does*, not *dose* - that is important. Would you like me to edit the remainder of your question? I tried to change the title, but the system wouldn't accept it because there is already another question with the same title - and the only reason yours got through was because of the spelling mistake. So I have changed it to *What can it mean?*

Comment: @WS2 : I'm sorry that my English is bad. I really want you to correct my English. I just started to use this site a few hours ago, so I really don't know how to use it. I read "HELP", but it will take long time to understand everything. Anyway, thank you very much for teaching me many things.

Comment: @istudyenglish Someone else had done some editing, but I have further changed a few things so that it does make entire grammatical sense. But I am not clear what is going on. *...he kicked them out*. Who is *he*? *One girl came and talked to "him" and they talked about Leon*. So if the *him* is Alex, and *he* kicked the girls out, what is Leon doing?

Comment: You might find this type of questions sits better at our sister site for [ell.se].

Comment: @WS Thank you very much for editing my question. It is very helpful for me to improve my English. Sorry about my grammar. "Alex was kicked out from other 3." "one girl came to talk to Alex, and they talked about Leon." I hope my sentences make sense.

Comment: @Matt E. Thank you very much for your advice. I did't know about English Language Learners. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have missed an important aspect. I've not seen "Casual", but I'm pretty sure that, when the conversation takes place, Leon and the second girl are, in fact, having sex (off-screen).

Leon's original refusal rose from the fact that he felt self-conscious with two women. The novelty of always being watched by a third party in what had always been a private activity (sex) had inhibited him.

Once in private with the second girl, his inhibitions have apparently vanished, to the point that Emily and Alex are quite aware of what's going on. So he's "doing very well". and Emily suggests that he is (obviously) no longer self-conscious.

Answer (score 0):

In a conversational fragment like "Not self-conscious at all" it's inferred that the person being talked about is the last subject of the conversation, in this case Leon. Alex is saying that Leon is not self-conscious.

"That's a big part of it", refers to Emmy's previous statement that Leon is doing very well. She's saying that not being self-conscious is a big part of Leon doing well.